# 86 / 5.000 Çeviri sonuçları I created my model, but I don't know exactly how to create the Dto. How can I do it?

Tags: model, dto, aspnetboilerplate

My intern and I created my model in relation to other tables. Now I need to create the Dto. I'm not completely sure and I'm a little confused when creating relationship structures. I need to create the Dto of my model. How can I create it without error? Can you help me?

My Model: Activity.cs

```
[Table("Activity")]
public class Activity : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    public int ScenarioId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductCodeId { get; set; }

    public decimal DiscountedPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal PromoMargin { get; set; }

    [Description("Covid Connected Shutdown Status")]
    public bool ShutdownStatus { get; set; }




    [ForeignKey("BrandId")]
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductCodeId")]
    public virtual ProductCode ProductCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ScenarioId")]
    public virtual Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
```

I need to create ActivityDto.cs

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Activity))]
public class ActivityDto : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    public decimal ActivityName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal DiscountedPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal PromoMargin { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Description("Covid Connected Shutdown Status")]
    public bool ShutdownStatus { get; set; }
}
```

How can i create other relations dto too. Do I need to keep their Id in the form of a new list?

Comment: *"Do I need to keep their Id in the form of a new list?"* What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Your Dto Class is inherited by `FullAuditedEntity<int>`.
It must be inherited like this `FullAuditedEntityDto<int>`

For the other relations, it is enough to describe relational entities id like this:

```
public id BrandId { get; set; }
public id CategoryId { get; set; }
.
.
.
.
```

Good luck!